# generate rows based on starting and ending numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server

say I have a table like this:

```
member  start_year  end_year
John    2013        2017
```

how to generate

```
member  year
John    2013
John    2014
John    2015
John    2016
John    2017
```

in SQL?

Comment: See https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/

Comment: You have far more than enough reputation to know what a bad question looks like, and that Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service. Please post your attempts, and explain  why it didn't work.

Comment: @Larnu i had totally no idea where to start... sorry...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical solution here involves a recursive CTE. First all the members are selected with the start and then recursively the following years are `UNION ALL`ed until the end is reached.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT t.member,
       t.start_year year
       FROM elbat t
UNION ALL
SELECT t.member,
       c.year + 1
       FROM cte c
            INNER JOIN elbat t
                       ON t.member = c.member
       WHERE c.year + 1 <= t.end_year
)
SELECT *
       FROM cte;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=33201bf004028900dcb53d65eb2407b3)

Comment: Try this: INSERT INTO elbat VALUES ('David',1900,2019);

Comment: @SlavaMurygin: Try this: `... FROM cte OPTION (maxrecursion 0);`.

Comment: Then fix your answer